# Connect USB serial dongle to Windows 7 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint, dongle

I am running Linux Mint 16, and VirtualBox 4.3.4, with the extension pack installed. I have Windows 7 installed as a client. I have to run an application on this Windows 7 install, and it uses a USB key with its serial in it. Unfortunately my desktop environment (Cinnamon) doesn't see this USB Key, so when I go into the USB sharing section in Settings, VirtualBox doesn't see it to share to the client.

I ran:

```
lsusb
```

and it comes up in that search shown here:

```
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0529:0001 Aladdin Knowledge Systems HASP v0.06
```

Do you know how to share a device like this with a Windows client?

Pls note: As of VirtualBox 4.x there is no longer 2 versions (Closed source and open source edition): https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions

Comment: You should read this post, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=924106 I never tried it, so I cannot offer any guidance, but this post claims to have made it work. First you will need to update the software on the key, the post tells you how.

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved a similar problem on my virtual machine :)

I installed the [virtualbox extension pack](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.36/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.36-105129.vbox-extpack) and then added my user to the vboxusers group `sudo adduser <your_username> vboxusers`. 
Finally I just selected the (now showing) usb device from the Devices->usb-devices menu in the started virtual machine.

Hope I could help (even if only as reference)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running the closed-source version of Virtualbox, not the OSE -- can you confirm that's the case here?

Comment: I figured OSE but then I looked into it and it seems there is only one version since 4.x as I read here:  https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions

Comment: oh and I have installed the extension pack

Comment: @DanielToebe - Update your question to reflect those facts.  This way you avoid answers like Simon's.

Comment: @DanielToebe -- right -- so have you installed the extension pack referred to there?

Comment: @simon Yes I have.